# Is it possible to create a mobile app with wifi P2P connection using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, cordova

Thanks for the help. I am really searching for this, but i can't see anything that proved that it is possible

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebRTC API to provide p2p connection. Here is some js plugin for doing that http://peerjs.com/. Problem with this solution is low support of browsers.

Another solution is use native iOS/Android api's through Cordova and controll them from Javascript.
This plugin will provide you Javascript interface to native p2p apis.
http://thaliproject.org/

Comment: Thanks sir. So if I make a p2p android game and process it via phonegap. Will it work?

Comment: Thali (best option for me) is primarily Cordova plugin, idk how it will work with phonegap. PhoneGap is built on top of Cordova, that means it should work :)

Comment: **Peerjs** is not so good solution, it need nodejs "peer server" for initializing connection between clients, **Thali** uses Bluetooth Low Energy/Bluetooth or WiFi direct for initializing connection between clients. Thats way better solution for mobile app.